# Can't install pdo_mysql with docker-php-ext-install

Tags: php, docker, image, build, dockerfile

I need help, I can’t install pdo_mysql, ampq or opcache with docker-php-ext-install. I prepared a docker project on a local PC (Mac OSX). On the local PC after build docker image is the final PHP configuration right. When I deploy the project config to the remote Debian server after building it, I have a completely different PHP version (phpinfo). Missing extensions opcache, pdo_mysql, ampq.

I tried to configure it differently and deleted the docker cache on the server, but it didn’t help.
`docker system prune -a`

My PHP dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN apt-get update \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

RUN apt update && apt-get udpate \
    && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip libxslt1-dev\
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install xsl

RUN apt-get update \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        librabbitmq-dev \
        libssh-dev \
    && pecl install amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o node_setup.sh && \
    bash node_setup.sh && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install npm -g

# Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y yarn

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
ADD ./crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
#
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
ADD ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/

# Copy docker entrypoint file
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Docker init
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a solution to your issue, but let's see.

From https://hub.docker.com/_/php:

`If you are having difficulty figuring out which Debian or Alpine packages need to be installed before docker-php-ext-install, then have a look at the install-php-extensions project. This script builds upon the docker-php-ext-* scripts and simplifies the installation of PHP extensions by automatically adding and removing Debian (apt) and Alpine (apk) packages. For example, to install the GD extension you simply have to run install-php-extensions gd. This tool is contributed by community members and is not included in the images, please refer to their Git repository for installation, usage, and issues.`

I had similar issues in the past and resolved it by using install-php-extensions. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613068/13467725).

Comment: That is not the this case.